# CEPH HA between 2 DC

Tags: high-availability, ceph

I have 2 datacenters with CEPH with 12 osd (DC1: 3osd x 2nodes, DC2: 3osd x 2nodes) and 1 pool with replicated size of 2.

The crush map:

```
ceph osd tree
ID   CLASS WEIGHT  TYPE NAME              STATUS REWEIGHT PRI-AFF 
-1       2.00000 root default                                   
-105       1.00000     datacenter 1                          
-102       1.00000         host f200pr03                          
4   ssd 1.00000             osd.4          up  1.00000 1.00000 
7   ssd 1.00000             osd.7          up  1.00000 1.00000 
10   ssd 1.00000             osd.10         up  1.00000 1.00000 
-103       1.00000         host f200pr04                          
5   ssd 1.00000             osd.5          up  1.00000 1.00000 
8   ssd 1.00000             osd.8          up  1.00000 1.00000 
11   ssd 1.00000             osd.11         up  1.00000 1.00000 
-104       1.00000     datacenter 2                         
-100       1.00000         host f200pr01  
   0   ssd 1.00000             osd.0          up  0.70007 1.00000 
   1   ssd 1.00000             osd.1          up  0.70007 1.00000 
   2   ssd 1.00000             osd.2          up  1.00000 1.00000 
-101       1.00000         host f200pr02                          
   3   ssd 1.00000             osd.3          up  0.70007 1.00000 
   6   ssd 1.00000             osd.6          up  0.70007 1.00000 
   9   ssd 1.00000             osd.9          up  1.00000 1.00000
```

And the pool has applied this crush rule:

```
# rules
rule replicated_rule {
    id 3
    type replicated
    min_size 1
    max_size 5
    step take default
    step chooseleaf firstn 2 type datacenter
    step emit
}
```

When I shutdown the datacenter 2 then datacenter 1 evolve a inconsistent status and "ceph status" finished with the message "Cluster connection aborted".

In ceph.conf I have the next configuration:

```
[global]
fsid = 48abdb31-95db-48d7-b2aa-835be95bfe3c
mon_initial_members = f200pr01, f200pr02, f200pr03, f200pr04
mon_host = 10.20.230.241,10.20.230.242,10.20.230.243,10.20.230.244
auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx
filestore_xattr_use_omap = true
mon_clock_drift_allowed = .15
mon_clock_drift_warn_backoff = 30
osd_journal_size = 10000
public_network = 10.20.230.0/24
```

¿What I need to change for add Datacenter HA in my environment? At this moment only support the shutdown of 1/4 nodes.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use replicated size 2 pools, it's a really bad idea and will lead to problems sooner or later. With ceph pacific there's a [stretch mode](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/operations/stretch-mode/) available which you had to setup manually prior to pacific.
In your case the cluster is not available because you have two MONs per DC and if one DC fails the remaining two MONs can't form a quorum. You need a fifth MON in a different datacenter to have a resilient cluster. As for the replication with two DCs it's either recommended to have a `pool size = 4` or use erasure-coded pools although your cluster is a little too small for that.